# How to send other variable datas along with new FormData() inside AJAX?

Tags: ajax, express, multipartform-data, form-data

Here I am sending the upload files into `FormData()` to be accessed in `expressjs`. And it is working perfectly.

```
  $(".commonForm").submit(function (e) { //For Submitting the Uploaded Files
      e.preventDefault();
      if(validateForm($(this).attr('name'), text))
      {
        $.LoadingOverlay("show");
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                if (response.status == '200') {
    
            $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
    
            swal({
            title: "Excellent!",
            text: "Files submitted successfully!",
            icon: "success",
            button: "Ok",
            showCancelButton: true
          }).then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
          });
    
            }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("some error", e);
            }
        });
     }
    });
```

But along with that I want to send one another field data along with `formData`.

```
 var text = 'Done';
```

How to send this along with formData in data ?
I am trying this:

```
data : {
formData:formData,
text:text
}
```

But then I don't think that I will be able to retrieve the uploaded files data directly with `req.files`

UPDATE:
route code/expressjs

```
  router.post('/api/upload/:cid',function(req,res,next){

console.log("req.body.text = " + req.body.text + req.query.text);

      upload2(req,res,function(err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log("Error is important = "+ err);
          }
          else
          {
            console.log("Uploaded successfully.");
}
})
})
```

MULTER CODE:

```
var upload2 = multer({storage: storage2, limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1 }}).array('FileUploadForClient',4);
```

HTML HANDLEBAR FORM CODE:

```
  <form  name="{{this.status}}" class="commonForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/api/upload/{{this.commonID}}" method="post">
    <td class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="center">
    <select name="sourcesSelect" id="{{this.commonID}}" data-notUse="{{this._id}}" data-Id4AddtasksBigpaths="{{this.Id4AddtasksBigpaths}}"  class="custom-select sources" placeholder="{{this.status}}" style="font-size:20px;  background: {{this.background}}; color: white;" {{this.statusDisabled}}>
      <option value="0" >In Progress</option>
      <option value="1" >Done</option>
      <option value="2" >Rejected</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </td>
    <!-- <td class="col-sm-2"><span id="deadline" style="font-size:14px"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{this.deadline}}" readonly/></span></td> -->
    <td class="col-sm-1">
      <!-- <input type="file" class="btn btn-light" name="FileUploadForClient" multiple required/> -->
      <input type="file" id="{{this._id}}" class="form-control" name="FileUploadForClient" multiple required {{this.statusDisabled}} />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block col-sm-2" style="font-size:16px" {{this.statusDisabled}}>Submit</button>
</td>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `append` to add another parameter to the request

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
formData.append('text', 'text to send in the request ');
```

Comment: How to access it in server side then? means How can I access the text field in route.get() in express? Like I am accessing the uploaded files as req.files @Musa

Comment: try  req.body.text

Comment: I am getting undefined :(

Comment: I am using enctype="multipart/form-data" since I need to use application/x-www-form-urlencode to parse the body. But here I want to access the multer files as well and also the text. What to do in that case? @Musa

Comment: Just updated :  route code/expressjs, multer and HTML HANDLEBAR FORM CODE:

Can you check now please? I am still getting undefined in console even I change the enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencode". @Musa